# Getting exception : AttributeError __aenter__

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I get this exception: "Exception has occurred: AttributeError __aenter__" in line `async with bot:`. (I entered the token). Please help

```
import asyncio
import telegram


async def main():
    bot = telegram.Bot("token")
    async with bot:
        print(await bot.get_me())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I found this code here: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API

Comment: Which version of the python-telegram-bot package do you have installed?

Comment: python-telegram-bot 13.11 |
Bot API 5.7 |
certifi 2022.05.18.1 |
Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: oh. The documentation in github was for 20.x version. I get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probobly that exception comming because you installed python-telegram-bot version 13.x.

try to:

> pip freeze

for check that, and if that true you have to make

> pip install python-telegram-bot --pre

because only unstable version use async.

Answer (score 5):

Think that's because you installed v13 (pip install python-telegram-bot) and the example you are looking at is from the v20 Github wiki.

Head over here for a quick start guide for v13 wrapper: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

**`print(bot.get_me())`**

with

`async with bot:  print(await bot.get_me())`

This is how I solved my problem.